# Why is there a // directory?

Tags: macos, unix, filesystems

I just found a very weird feature (bug?) with my computer's file system. I can do `cd //` and it will go to the `//` directory, but display all the same files as the `/` directory. Why is this? If I `cd ..` while in `/`, it will stay at `/`. `//` is the only one that works -- I tried multiple slashes, but it just stays in `/`.

Comment: What does `/bin/pwd` report when you're in `//`? Also, which shell are you using?

Comment: @larsmans `pwd` tells me I'm in `//`. I'm using bash.

Comment: Is that `pwd` or `/bin/pwd`?

Comment: Both say the same thing.

Comment: Same results on ubuntu. // is root.

Comment: Already answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/what-do-double-slashes-mean-in-unix-path-is-cd-dir-subdir-valid

Comment: Some words on _why_ this is: if you've written a few shell scripts, you'll notice that it is very easy to end up with multiple sequential slashes after concatenating paths if not careful. Since there is no ambiguity (by design: nothing can be named "[nothing]"), POSIX says: behave nicely in case of '//'. It's the [principle of  least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) in application :-) .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/):

3.266: ... Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.

4.11: ... A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

The second part means that a path beginning with // can have a special meaning.  This is rarely if ever used, and can be a source of bugs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816833/163956.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Bash will normalize pathnames, but does not normalize double slashes at the beginning of a pathname. This is understandable, as on some Unix systems (though not Mac OS X), `//` may indicate a network path and Bash is intended to be portable. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and) on Unix.SE for the double-slash issue.

Since in Mac OS X `//` has no special meaning, you're actually in `/`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between // and /. It's just bash being tolerant of multiple slashes.

Note you can also use // in paths and it won't complain, and it will treat them just like /.