# Lost my files while moving on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mv

I used the command on CLI -

```
aws s3 mv s3://<source_directory_path> <destination_directory_path> --recursive


aws s3 mv s3://<source_directory_path> s3://<destination_directory_path> --recursive
```

Missed the `s3://` in the above one—it did move all the files—but I am not sure where.

Comment: What OS did you do this on? It could be in your root directory under `://`.

Comment: If you are on macOS or some Linux/Unix system they could just be on root. Look [at this for more info](https://superuser.com/q/401593/167207).